# Keep HTML image and text next to each other and the text not under the picture

Tags: html, css

In the following excercise, the text continues under the photo:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float2

Is there a way of keeping the text to the right of the picture, no matter how much text there is, then follow it with another picture and text and so forth?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css on your `img` tag:

```
float: right;
```

This will keep the image on the right hand side.

In your example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNJU9KRYTVUA

Please note that you should read more into the float topic, because you also have to clear the float in a specific way. Please see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Duplicate link answered my question, thanks v much pal.